# How to load an image asset from a list of assets in the folder?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, list

I have a folder in my Assets that contains 44 images.

I want to add them to the Map in sequence.  However I'm getting an error that I can only create an image that is a constant.

```
var image = ee.Image("users/JASPR/Lotes/La_Pampa/Parametros/MVTCatrilo38000") // This works fine.

var assetList = ee.List(ee.data.getList({'id':"users/JASPR/Lotes/La_Pampa/Parametros"}))

print(assetList) //List (44 elements)

var value = ee.Dictionary(assetList.get(3)) // get the third element
var myID = ee.String(value.get('id')) // get the id 

print(myID) // "users/JASPR/Lotes/La_Pampa/Parametros/MVTCatrilo38000"

var image2 = ee.Image(myID) // Image (Error) Actual value for parameter 'id' must be a constant.


// Obviously, as a result of the error above, all that follows doesn't work.
print("image",image2)
Map.centerObject(image2)
Map.addLayer(image2)
```

When I replace the "myID" variable with the string:

```
"users/JASPR/Lotes/La_Pampa/Parametros/MVTCatrilo38000"
```

it loads the image perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not understand why it doesn't work by casting the dictionary.get() to an ee.String, however it should work when you use .getInfo() on your image ID.

```
var myID = ee.String(value.get('id')).getInfo() // get the id   
print(myID) // "users/JASPR/Lotes/La_Pampa/Parametros/MVTCatrilo38000"

var image2 = ee.Image(myID)
print("image",image2)
```

Comment: getInfo() did the trick.  Thanks!

It must have something to do with the server side variable not being readable by the ee.Image() when it is just read from value.get('id')

Comment: Yes it possibly is, however it's strange as ee.Image() should accept strings as input.